# PowerPivot DAX measure Filtering

Tags: dax, powerbi

I am starting to use all de PowerBI tools for a customer.

On the data they have three shops (1,2 and 4, named in the table "botiga") and diferent departments (named in the table "departament").

I need to calculate the sales (named "vendes" or Ventas[import]) of all the departments and all the shops but I have to exclude in the calculation the ones that correspond to the shop 1 and 2 and also correspond to the department 61.
All the realated columns are in the same table named "Ventas"

I did it and it Works with this measure:

vendes sense carnisseria:=[Vendes]-SUMX(FILTER(Ventas;Ventas[Botiga]<>"4" && Ventas[Departament]="61");Ventas[Import])

Vendes:=sum(Ventas[Import])

But I am sure that theri is a better way to do it, I have tried to do like in excel when we do SUMIF but doesn't seems to work.

I use FILTER beacouse I want that the data filters used in the associated pivot table remain.

Answer (score 1):

[Calculate is like a supercharged Sumif](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2009/12/powerpivot-dax-calculate-is-a-supercharged-sumif/).

Try something like

Carnisseria:=
    [vendes] - Calculate([vendes];Ventas[Botiga]<> "4"; Ventas[Departament]="61")

I would also check that you want any shop that isn't #4 or if you want just shops #1 and #2. While that yields the same results right now, it may not in the future.

Comment: Hi Mmarie, I tried your solution and it gives me an error "Error de cálculo en la medida 'Ventas'[Prova]: La expresión contiene varias columnas, pero en una expresión True/False que se usa como expresión de filtro de tabla solo puede utilizarse una columna.
In English is: "Miscalculation of the measure 'Sales' [Prova]: The expression contains multiple columns, but a True / False expression used as a filter expression table column can only be used."

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to go back and edit the formula to remove the &&. I was interpreting your logic one way and then decided it could just be a regular calculate with multiple filters and forgot to go back and edit. Try the edited formula. The syntax of calculate is simply CALCULATE(<expression>,<filter1>,<filter2>…). You can check it out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634825.aspx).

Comment: Also, are your store numbers and departments really strings? If they are actually integers they don't need quotes around them.

Comment: Mmarie, if I put your formula it filter first for shop 4 and then it takes out the department 61. What I need is to have all the sales of all the shops and all the departments except the sales of the department 61 in the shops 1 and 2. My formula Works but I think that, for sure, that there is a better way to do it. You are right the Store and the departments are strings. I have to change them to integers.

Comment: Ok, so do sales - minus my calculation

Comment: If I understand, you want total sales minus the sales that are department 61 in stores that are not 4. that is what my updated calculation gives you now. The only thing I did was add the [vendes] - at the front. Using filter is incredibly slow and inefficient. http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2010/04/quick-tip-dont-over-use-filter/

Comment: If this isn't what you need then I'm not really understanding what your desired result should be. So in general try to use calculate or calculate table rather than filter. Good luck!